# When to use keystores and when not to?

Tags: java, security

I have a server side application, that is required to make secured communication with other applications deployed else where. I do have all the information that I need per client(user of my server app) to initiate SSL connection. So, I have client CERT - containing public key, and client private key to be used for SSL and also CA cert that is being used by external application for SSL authentication.

I initiate the SSL connection programatically from within my server application.

So, for every client I create an SSLContext, using an in-memory keystore with all the above imported to it. The various certs and keys are imported programatically using data from my DB. (Note: All of the SSL artefacts are stored in an encrypted manner in DB).

Now my question is that Should I use a physical keystore(A java keystore stored in filesystem) or can I keep all security info in my Database as encrypted blobs.

What is the industry recommended way for the above usecase and why. Any guidelines for the above will be greatly appreciated ...

Comment: For all informations on how to do SSL connections I have used http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html as reference.